# How to calculate the current in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

How can i calculate the current i the one in the running thru the 50 Ohm resistance, here [image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be academic work, but does not show how poster attempted to solve problem.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy idk what to do. What am I supposed to write?

Comment: Explain in your post what your thinking process is, and where you became stuck.

Comment: HellBoy. We are happy to help with academic work BUT the site rules require that you tell us what you have tried and what you understand. Our aim is to help you in the learning process, not to just tell you the answer.  || Please avoid even indirect references to 'impolite language'. We try to stay clear of the 'slippery slope' :-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can i calculate the current i the one in the running thru the 50
> Ohm resistance*

**Hint:** The 120 volt source and its series 10 Ω resistor can be converted to a 12 amp current source parallel to a 10 Ω resistor. So now you have a 12 amp source in parallel with a 6 amp source feeding a 10 Ω resistor in parallel with a 50 Ω resistor.

That should be enough of a hint for you to calculate what you need.

If you want a theorem name, it's called a Thevenin transformation.

Comment: Im confused about the current coming from both sides of the circuit, shall i use kirchoff current rule so : 12A + 6A =i?

Comment: Yes, currents are additive but, that current is shared by the 10 ohm and the 50 ohm.

Comment: we wont bother with the 10 ohm bcz we replaced that part of circuit with a current generator of 12 amps , no?

Comment: @HellBoy no, the transformation takes a voltage source in series with a 10 ohm resistor and makes it into a current source in parallel with a 10 ohm resistor.

Comment: so we turn the voltage current into a 12 amp source current and the 10 ohm resistor stays in parallel with the 50 ohm resistor? what about the other parallel 6amp current source.

Comment: The two current sources add up and combine.

Comment: so the current flowing thru the 50 ohm resistor is 18 A?

Comment: No, current in both the 10 ohm and 50 ohm in parallel is 18 amps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147696/discussion-between-hellboy-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score -2):

Assuming all the arrows on the left side mean, that the voltage source can not take a current, all the current produced by the right side, i.e. the 6 A have to go through the 50 ohm, so that's the answer. Also the voltage delivered by the current source will be 300 V and the left side is irrelevant.

Comment: what? wym irrelevant?

Comment: Because no current can go into it by assumption and not current can come out of it, because 120 is less than 300.

Comment: Because with all due respect I think the answer by Andy aka is wrong. You can not simply convert a voltage into a current source. These are different concepts.

Comment: no you are wrong, the devices are in parallel so they must have the same tension

Comment: A voltage source can have current flowing into or out of it. The voltage source only has to do one thing and that is maintain the voltage at 120 volts. If that means taking current then that's what it will do @Čäřý

Comment: @Andy aka. Very well, as explained my assumption was based on the arrows. So let's assume they mean nothing. Than let as denote the voltage at the 50 ohm and the 6A source as V, the current through 50 ohm as I50, and the current through 10 ohm as I10. This gives the system of linear equations with two unknowns I50 and I10 i.e. I10 + I50 = 6 and I50 * 50 = V = I10 * 10 + 120.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are miles off course with this. Get a simulation tool and make the circuit and see what the voltages reveal and, look what current flows into the voltage source. Better still, ask a new formal question and ask for help.

Comment: The current that flows into the voltage source is the inverse current to what flows out of the voltage source, which is I10, so it is -I10.